Is a question about the classes/subclasses in Baldur's Gate 3 on topic?
I want to ask a question about how many of the official DnD classes/subclasses from DnD 5E Baldur's Gate 3 has. I also want to know if they have any that 5E doesn't.
Is this on topic?

Sounds fine to me, so ask away.

I would guess here is better than fantasy or board games because even if its 5E, what I heard is that a lot of it was adapted and changed to make it work within a video game. Havent played it yet tho.

@Fredy31: Many aspects were really messed with. One of the major changes is that DnD uses real time (e.g. a spell might say that it takes 10 minutes to cast) and BG3 uses video game time (time advances when you take a long rest, or during battles at the end of each turn, and is otherwise an eternal "now"). Lots of rules and mechanics had to be altered to accommodate that difference.

@Kevin I'd also add that since its a video game that needs to be programmed, there is no such thing as 'check with your DM if he allows it'. Its allowed or its not. Thats a major difference into how the dynamic is very different than the board game.

@wipqozn Are you sure that the question isn't too broad? I asked the question (https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/408058/regarding-the-classes-and-subclass-in-baldurs-gate-iii) and that's what one comment said. Would you know how to keep the meaning intact while focusing it (if it needs focusing)?

The question itself is ok, but you asked 5 different questions in a single post, and that's too broad.

@Daemons I reopened your question after trimming it down to exactly what your originally proposed here. As others have stated, your question was too broad to be answerable with a single question. Later today, when I have time, I'll post some additional details here on why the original question was too broad, and the best approach for you to get answers to all your questions.

The problem with your posted question
The original version of the question you posted, which you can view here, was too broad for a single question on Arqade. That essentially means you were asking too many questions at once. There's multiple problems with doing this, with the main one being that any answer would just be way too large to fit into a single answer (answers do have character limits).
Another problem though is that it becomes a lot harder for any user to actually answer your question(s), since they need to post an answer which covers all your questions. This is a lot to ask of any single user, since that's a huge time commitment from them. You also need to consider that a user might know the answer to one of your questions, but not the rest. In those situations a user couldn't post an answer, since any answer they post would be incomplete.
The end result of all these problems is you don't get an answer to your question(s), which obviously isn't what you want. In other words, it's better for you to avoid asking questions that are too large.
The Solution
The fix to this is to just ask multiple  smaller questions instead. Questions which are smaller and more narrowly focused don't suffer from any of the problems that gigantic questions suffer from. You're far more likely to get an answer to all of your questions if you post them as smaller separate questions instead of as one giant question.
Your Specific Case
For your specific case, I've edited your question to just focus on which classes are shared between 5E and Baldur's Gate 3.
For your question around how spell lists and abilities have changed for the classes, I'd say that your best approach would to make a question for each of the classes you're interested in. For each of those classes, I'd make a question asking "What are the major changes made to [some class] in Baldur's Gate 3 compared to 5E?"
The inclusion of Major Changes instead of just Changes is because asking for all changes made even to just a single class (especially spellcasters) has the potential to be too large of a question all on its own. It's better to just focus on any major changes made, which is not only far more narrow in scope, but is a far more interesting question than just asking for a complete list of every change (no matter how trivial) made to the classes in the game.
